# Is it better to use container class variables or a pointer of container class in function?

Tags: c++

In my program, I need several `std::vector` and `std::list` in a class member function:

```
void classA::function(){
   vector<glm::ivec3> tmpContainer[5];
}
```

or

```
void classA::function(){
   vector<glm::ivec3> **tmpContainer;
   tmpContainer = new vector<glm::ivec3>*[5];
   for(int i = 0;i < 5;++i){
       tmpContainer[i] = new vector<glm::ivec3>;
   }
}
```

Which is better, both can work, first is convenient, but I'm concerned that if the number of vector increases, more than 10 for example, the first may fail, so I write the second.

Comment: `vector<glm::ivec3> **tmpContainer;` is most of the time a code-smell. There is rarely ever any reason to do this, especially since `std::vector` already manages dynamically allocated memory itself

Comment: The first is best, why would it fail? Don't make programming more complicated that it needs to be. For some reason some beginners love pointers, and use them when they are unnecessary. All it does is add extra complexity.

Comment: I guess your concern might be stack overflow, but 10 is a very small number and vectors are very small objects. Most of the data that a vector uses will always be on the heap, only a few internal pointers will be on the stack.

Comment: tmpContainer would probably need to be a `std::vector<std::vector<glm::ivec3>> tmpContainer` or an `std::array<std::vector<glm::ivec3>,5>`

Comment: In general in current C++ you should be able to avoid the use of `new`/`delete` completely (unless you are writing the internals of a datastructure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first option is better, it fits in one line, has no leaks and reads easily.

The second one have more lines, is harder to read, contain leaks and potential for more leaks. Remember that even if you delete the elements you allocated later in the function, if an exception is thrown the memory will leak.

If you need more than 5 vectors, use a vector of vectors. It will be clear, leak free, and efficient.

There are many "good style rules" about C++, one of them is to never write "new". It's actually not a bad one.

Comment: If a large vector<vector<glm::ivec3>> as temporary variable in function, will there be a large footprint on stack? Or vector will allocate the memory in heap, so no worry about this issue?

Comment: No, vector allocates memory dynamically, there is no stack issue here.